# cache_size effect on SVC processing time

Tags: performance, scikit-learn

I've done a cross-validated SVC analysis. Reading the scikit-learn docs for svc, I see this:

"Kernel cache size: For SVC, SVR, nuSVC and NuSVR, the size of the kernel cache has a strong impact on run times for larger problems. If you have enough RAM available, it is recommended to set cache_size to a higher value than the default of 200(MB), such as 500(MB) or 1000(MB)."

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html

So I re-ran my analysis several times and timed the results using several different values for cache_size (50, 100, 200, 800, 1200, 2000, 4000, 8000).

My full analysis takes about 11.2 seconds when the cache_size is below 2000, and the time jumps to 40 seconds when the cache_size is greater than 2000.

The analysis takes place on a modern computer with 16 gigabytes of ram.

I'm wondering if anybody knows possible reasons why the processing time wouldn't change at all for any cache value below 2000, and why the processing time would get *longer* with higher values. Again, the computer has 16 gigs of ram and no signs of otherwise slowing occurs at any value of cache_size.

Thank you for anybody's thoughts.

Comment: Just guessing, but you might with a cache size of 4000 or 8000MB you could be significantly reducing the RAM available for processing. This might slow down the actual algorithm.

Comment: @amanbirs That's possible. It makes sense to me - If the cache is just a place to store things for later use it makes sense that a certain "upper limit" of performance could be reached quickly in smaller problems, where adding more room to the cache just removes the possibility of using that RAM for the actual computations.

Comment: Yeah, especially if the cache size = 8GB. Tha's half the total RAM. The available RAM is probably considerably less than that.

Comment: From a theory-standpoint i would say: it should not slow down. Take your favorite process-manager and observe the memory consumption during the whole task. IF you hit the limit, trashing will occur and will slow things down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The slow-down you noticed for cache > 2000 MB may be the consequence of this bug: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8012 (signed 32-bit integer overflow).